# Improper Integral Question

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Express $$\int_0^1x^m(1-x^n)^pdx$$ in terms of gama function and hence evaluate the integral.

I used the substitution $x^n=y$ and solving got this integral as equal to the beta-function
$${1\over n}\beta({{{m+1}\over n},{p+1}})$$ solving futher by converting to gamma function ($\gamma)$ i get

## $${1 \over n}[{{\Gamma({m+1 \over n})\Gamma(p+1)}} \over \Gamma({{m+1} \over n}+p+1)$$

and the answer i finally get is

$$p\over (m+p-1)!(m+np+1)$$

Is it correct ? One doubt i had in the solution is can we write

$$\Gamma(a+p)={{(a+p-1)!} \over (a-1)!} \Gamma(a)$$  ??

Comment: At first I thought it was a question about an improper integral. But you integral does not seem improper, so perhaps it is an improper question about an integral? (English is such a weird language sometimes.)

Comment: Your answer looks suspicious, because unless you write it in terms of gamma functions, it can't possibly be true for the case when m and/or n and/or p aren't positive whole numbers.

Comment: For your last question, no you can't do that. $\Gamma(a+p)=(a+p-1)(a+p-2)\cdots a\cdot\Gamma(a)$, and you can't simplify that the way you suggested.

Comment: LOL!!! No its not an imroper question about integration. I mean a Euler Integral. Here you will see that for m<0 the integral will become improper

Comment: how did you write that gamma  ?

Comment: @AmanMittal to make a capital greek letter, use a capital to start the LaTeX command: `\gamma` $\to \gamma$, and `\Gamma` $\to \Gamma$

Comment: Like so: `\Gamma`

Comment: @anorton I mean the gamma function that you have mentioned. i was not able to find out how to write that here.

Comment: i guess there is a problem in the step where i write $\Gamma(a+p)=(a+p-1)!\Gamma(a)$ Any clue about that ?

Is there any rule that can reduce $\Gamma(a+p)$ to something * $\Gamma(a)$

Comment: @Is $a$ guaranteed to be integer-valued?  (Or at least, is $a+p$ guaranteed to be integer-valued?

Comment: Lets say yes, coz nothing is mentioned in the question.

Comment: I think i figured it out. Should it not be $$\Gamma(a+p)={{(a+p-1)!} \over (a-1)!} \Gamma(a)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1x^m(1-x^n)^p\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1u^{m/n}(1-u)^p\,\mathrm{d}u^{1/n}\\
&=\frac1n\int_0^1u^{(m+1)/n-1}(1-u)^p\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac1n\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{n}\right)\Gamma(p+1)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{n}+p+1\right)}\\
&=\frac{p}{m+1+pn}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{n}\right)\Gamma(p)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{n}+p\right)}
\end{align}
$$
So your initial answer looks good. However, I don't see how you get from there to
$$
\frac{p}{(m+p-1)!(m+np+1)}
$$

In the last question, for integer $n$, $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$. The rest is simply cancellation.